# How to convert TSQL aggregate function to Postgresql

Tags: sql, t-sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am having difficulty converting a view from T-SQL to Postgresql as it relates to the aggregate functions.

Here is my original SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    thread_id, 
    MIN(message_id) AS message_id,  
    MIN(parent_message_id) AS parent_message_id, 
    MIN(created_at) AS initialResponse
FROM 
    dbo.bi_linear_thread
WHERE 
    LEFT([subject], 5) LIKE '%RE:%' AND parent_message_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    thread_id
ORDER BY 
    thread_id
```

I have attempted to utilize the window function of:

```
first_value(message_id) OVER (Partition BY message_id ORDER BY messageid)
```

but continue to get incorrect returns.

Thoughts?

#### Edit for more context

-- after the answer provided.  Hopeful this is helpful to others.

Needed to read the first line in a group that excluded the first record in a hierarchal order of threads to replies.
`thread_id` represents the thread.
`message_id` represents any message type whether a reply/original message. `parent_message_id` represents the original message in the thread.
"RE:" is a specified format for replies regardless whether nested or not in the subject field.

Comment: I can't find a table definition in your question or any explanation as to what you are trying to achieve, nor your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT thread_id
      ,MIN(message_id) AS message_id
      ,MIN(parent_message_id) AS parent_message_id
      ,MIN(created_at) AS initialResponse
FROM   dbo.bi_linear_thread
WHERE  left(subject, 5) LIKE '%RE:%'
AND    parent_message_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY thread_id
ORDER  BY thread_id;
```

Except for removing the illegal brackets from `[subject]` and also removing `TOP (100) PERCENT`, which is just noise anyway, the query should work.

You might want `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` for case-insensitive pattern-matching.

`left()` was introduced with Postgres 9.1.

If you want CaMeL-case identifiers you need to double-quote: "initialResponse". Else they are lower-cased automatically. My advice is to use lower-case identifiers exclusively.

#### Educated guess

**If** you actually want the row with the earliest `created_at` per `thread_id`, which you cunningly kept a secret, your query is *incorrect*, tSQL or PostgreSQL alike.
You could use `DISTINCT ON` for that.

You probably don't have a schema named `dbo` in Postgres either, and that's an artifact from SQL Server, so I removed that, too.

I use `ILIKE` as explained above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (thread_id)
       thread_id, message_id, parent_message_id, created_at AS initial_response
FROM   bi_linear_thread
WHERE  left(subject, 5) ILIKE '%RE:%'
AND    parent_message_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY thread_id, created_at;
```

Information on `DISTINCT ON`:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For perfomance, a trigram GIN [index on the expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) `left(subject, 5)` might help quite a bit. More info:
[PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Comment: Thanks, that cleans up the dirty TSQL...

I'm going from T-SQL to Postgresql 8.2.x errr whatever...

Comment: @standardcandle-: **8.2**?? Really?? That is extremely outdated and has been unsupported for some while now. You should really go for 9.2 instead. Do not use 8.2

Comment: @standardcandle-: What a_horse said. [Consider this](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Maybe just a typo and you meant 9.2? `left()` does not exist in 8.2 for starters.

Comment: Thanks for your help... you were 100% right... I had ~3% error on records on the way I was trying to do it.  I was unaware of the DISTINCT ON 

As for the version... I'm using an outdated version of GreenPlum, and waiting on IT to upgrade the environment.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This was the closest I came on my own... better answer above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 thread_id
,first_value(message_id) OVER (Partition BY thread_id ORDER BY message_id) AS message_id
,first_value(parent_message_id) OVER (Partition BY thread_id ORDER BY parent_message_id) AS parent_message_id
,first_value(created_at) OVER (Partition BY thread_id ORDER BY created_at) AS initialResponse 
FROM bi_linear_thread
WHERE parent_message_id IS NOT NULL AND subject ~* '.*RE:.*'
GROUP BY message_id, thread_id, parent_message_id, created_at
ORDER BY thread_id desc
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient query. Should be simplified with `min()` and `GROUP BY`, similar to what you had and like I posted.

Comment: Agreed it was inefficient... and inaccurate.  Thanks for you help, see my response above. :D